# create JSON_ARRAY() from GROUP_CONCAT()

Tags: mysql

let's say `my_database` has `tbl1` `tbl2` `tbl3` like tables

I want to make an `JSON_ARRAY` with table names from `my_database`

I tried:

```
SET @bd = 'my_database';

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT TABLE_NAME) INTO @my_tables
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @bd;

SELECT JSON_ARRAY(@my_tables);
```

But I got a single element array

```
+-------------------+
| @my_tables         |
+-------------------+
| ["tbl1,tbl2,tbl3"] |
+-------------------+
```

I'm looking for `["tbl1","tbl2","tbl3"]`

Comment: your variable stores a string.  use json_arrayagg instead of group_concat to get a json array instead. mysql does not support json_arrayagg distinct, though mariadb does.  if you truly need distinct, select from a distinct subquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(TABLE_NAME) INTO @my_tables
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @bd;
```

There's no need to use `DISTINCT` in this query, because `TABLE_NAME` is guaranteed to be unique within a specific schema.

JSON_ARRAYAGG() requires MySQL 5.7.22 or later. If you have an older version of MySQL, it's time to upgrade.